# Combing Word files with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, runtime-error

I'm developing a macro with VBA.  It starts with an Excel data file that fills in certain fields in a Word template and saves each document with a unique name.  So far so good.

The next step is to combine all of the Word documents into a "main" Word document so I can save it as a PDF file.  The way I'm combining Word files is using the Insert > Object > Text from file.  When I tried it in the "main" Word document and recording the code, it worked and combined the Word documents like I expected it to.

I took that code and moved it to my Excel macro but I'm getting an error message.  The error message says: Run-Time error '438':  Object doesn't support this property or method."

Here is the code I'm trying to use to combine the Word documents into the "main" document.

```
Set WrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WrdApp.Visible = True
    
vTmp2 = ""
vTmp2 = FilePath1 & "MainDoc.doc"
    
Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Open(vTmp2)
        
Y = 1
DocCnt = 2
    
ChangeFileOpenDirectory FilePath2
    
Do Until Y > X
    
        DoEvents

'      ***Error occurs on the following line:***    
        WrdDoc.InsertFile Filename:="Flyer Row " & DocCnt & ".doc", Range:="", _
            ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False

'       ***Following is the recorded code:***        
'       Selection.InsertFile Filename:="Flyer Row 2.doc", Range:="", _
'           ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
'
'       Selection.InsertFile Filename:="Flyer Row 3.doc", Range:="", _
'           ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
'
'       Selection.InsertFile Filename:="Flyer Row 4.doc", Range:="", _
'           ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
    
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    
        ActiveDocument.Save
        
        Y = Y + 1
        DocCnt = DocCnt + 1
        
Loop
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong with this code.  I've checked the variables and they all have the expected values, so that's not it.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for the help

Comment: `Filename:="Flyer Row " & DocCnt & ".doc"` is missing a path to the file. Fixing that would eliminate that as a possibility at least.

Comment: InsertFile is a method of the Selection object or a Range object, but you are using a Document object. You need either a range, e.g. WrdDoc.Content.InsertFile, or to create a Word.Range object that points to the correct place to insert the file.

Comment: @braX....thanks for the suggestion.  that was part of the issue...

Comment: @slightlysnarky..........Thanks......I changed it to use Content and it worked.  the only issue I'm still having is that it overlays each file in the "main" document.  How do I get it to add a page to the "main" document or insert a page break at the end of the file it just inserted.  It work just like I wanted it to in Word but having a

Comment: @slightlysnarky an issue getting it work in Excel.  I'm close.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your help.........Shaves

Comment: @Shaves You didn't say what went wrong but if you need to use a variable that's a *Word* Range then you have to declare it as a Word.Range, because that's a differetype from an Excel.Range. And you can usually insert at the end of a document using *something like* Dim rng As Word.Range Set rng = WrdDoc.Content rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd rng.Insertfile <whatever>

Comment: @slightlysnarky............Sorry about that.  I know better than to say it doesn't work with out any details.  When the macro ran from Excel, it would overwrite the data.  So instead of 3 pages in the "main" document, I only had 1 page with the last row from the data source.  The good news is I continued to work with it and I now have all 3 pages in the correct order.  Thanks for you help.....